# Bring up confirmation page on closing modal

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I want to be able to click outside of a modal to close it, but can't find a way to stop the clickOutsideToClose event from propagating. So far I've tried OnRemoving, which does get called when the modal is being closed, but event.stopImmediatePropagation() does not stop the modal from closing.

```
$scope.openModal = function(){
            $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: 'app/summary/example.modal.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullScreen: true,
                locals:{
                    step: {name: 'openingPage'}
                },
                controller : function($scope, step){
                    $scope.step = step;
                },
                onRemoving: function(event, removePromise){
                    console.log('OnRemoving called');
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            }).then(function(){
                console.log('inside success function of show then');
            }, function(){
                ExampleFactory.clearAll();
            });
        };
```

I'm using the scope variable step to move between pages of the modal, so I want to be able to set that for the confirm page when a clickOutsideToClose event happens. Actually closing the modal would happen on the confirm page with yes/no buttons.

```
<md-dialog class="exampleModal">
    <md-dialog-content>
        <div ng-switch="step.name">
            <opening-page ng-switch-when="openingPage" step="step"></opening-page>
            <confirmation-page ng-switch-when="confirm" step="step"></confirmation-page>
        </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: [On the documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog), `onRemoving - function(element, removePromise)` this shows the first argument is the element, not an event.

Comment: Perhaps an alternative is to set the `clickOutsideToClose` to false and use `onShowing` and `onRemoving` to wire and unwire your click events.  I don't see any clean/built-in solutions for this.